# Create a docker image of the mongoDB- atlas version

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, mongodb-atlas

Hello I want to containarize my flask app and my mongo annd connect them. I have already containerize the flask app.
my current code:

**Dockerfile for flask container**

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
WORKDIR /ergasiav3
ADD . /ergasiav3
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

I have a **db.py** with the **connection to the mongoDB**, here is the code:

```
from flask_pymongo import pymongo


CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.sqowy.mongodb.net/InfoCinemas?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)
db = client.get_database('InfoCinemas')
Users = pymongo.collection.Collection(db, 'Users')
Movies = pymongo.collection.Collection(db, 'Movies')
```

I also created this docker-compose.yml which seems to work but I dont know how to get the mongo as an image too.

```
version: '3'

services:
  infocinemas:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./ergasiav3
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Do I need to make a second Dockerfile or do I just make the docker-compose.yml for the conterization of mongoDB?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: OPA! If you are using atlas you don't need a separate mongo container, your data is in atlas.

Comment: oh okay thanks for that!

Comment: It it's as easy as that, then mark my answer as correct to save others time trying to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate mongo container, your data is in atlas.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/docker

I also have this same question today as I have just started docker.

No need of separate container if you are using atlas

The information is located at the last of article

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to deploy an atlas cluster locally, using docker and or docker compose. it's not suggested for production, but if you don't want to have to open up access to your atlas cluster for a dev database, it's a great solution, especially if you're developing a solution that leverages their vector embedding and search features, which require an atlas cluster.  [See the Atlas docs for more info](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/atlas-cli-deploy-docker/#std-label-atlas-cli-deploy-docker)